# Google re-captcha not working in existing php form

Tags: php, recaptcha

Please be patient, I'm new at this. :) I can't seem to get Google re-captcha to work in my existing php form - see below. I am sure I need to remove or add code. Also, I'd like the re-captcha to validate before submitting to my email. Thank you so much.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):

    $secret = 'secret key';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
    if($responseData->success):


//redirect if login was successful
header('Location: ./xxxx.hmtl');

$myemail = 'email@hotmail.com';
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
echo "Email:".$email."<br>";
echo "Subject:".$subject."<br>";
echo "Message:".$message."<br>";

if ($_POST['subject'] ) { 
echo 'Tastes Like Spam!'; }
else {
$success = true; mail($myemail);
```

}

```
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "xxxx.com New Message: $subject";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Details are below:\n Subject: $subject \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message: \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

}

?>

My html form code is below. I am not sure why it doesn't redirect to the home page nor submits the form. It goes to an error page - basically the .php url. Thanks for your help and being patient :)

```
    <div class="section-container-spacer">
        <form action="process.php" class="reveal-content" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" required=""></textarea>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site key goes here"></div></div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <ul class="list-unstyled address-container">
                <li> <span class="fa-icon"> <i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> <a href="mailto:email@.hotmail.com">email@hotmail.com</a> </li>
                <li> <span class="fa-icon"> <i class="fa fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> Los Angeles, CA </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Your message has been sent. We will be in touch.");
}
</script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
$("input#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#thanks").html(msg) 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
});
  </script> 
      </div>
```

Comment: whats the exact problem?

Comment: Do `var_dump($responseData);` to see if there's an error.

Comment: Post your html code as well.

Comment: @smith After hitting "submit" it goes to an error page. Does not re-direct to homepage nor submit form information to email.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Which part of html?

Comment: @Brittany the form part.

Comment: nothing in your code redirects to any error page.

Comment: @KarloKokkak I have added the form code :)
Also, I wonder if the script code below the form code is messing everything up. I believe it's my php code that is wrong but I could be all wrong.